# Avoiding situation when nova.conf file overwritten by juju

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, nova

I use MAAS, Juju for Ubuntu Openstack.

For novnc console access, i need to modify the nova.conf file.

But that might be overwritten by Juju. Actually it is overwritten, i found at least one situation - new nova-compute unit.

So, where can I in Juju specify, the extra config which i want to have in nova.conf file?

I would like to have permanent in nova.conf file for example this:

> vncserver_proxyclient_address=X.X.X.X
>
> nonvncproxy_base_url="__"
>
> vncserver_listen=X.X.X.X

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best thing todo is to wait until this Thursday (23rd October) and then upgrade to the latest release of OpenStack Charms, which support console configuration options using spice or vnc via the charm itself, rather than you having to hack stuff into you environment directly:

```
juju set nova-cloud-controller console-access-protocol=spice
```

should then just DTRT both on the controller node and the compute nodes.

Comment: Thank you for an answer. 1) Is this info, roadmap, date somewhere public?

Comment: 2) I found (just now) that for nova-compute charm (luckily my situation) I can use juju set config-flags='key1=value,key2=value' list. This adds the pairs to nova.conf. Is this the right approach as well?